# How To Check If My Website Is Up Or Down?

Tags: html

So, I'm currently using A system where I can manually say if the website is online or not; but I don't see this as "Efficient" because I won't be there 24/7. So I was wondering if there was a way to check if their website is online or not and then create a file on a server as soon as it goes down?

Comment: There is no way to check internally if a site is online or not. What can the server do if it crashes or down? The answer is: not a lot. Generally you use an external service for this. [DotComMonitor](https://www.dotcom-monitor.com/) is just one example of such a service.

Answer (score 1):

You can use free service like [UptimeRobot](https://uptimerobot.com/). It will send you notification when the site is down or back up.

Answer (score 1):

I wrote simple script in python. Script simple check website status.
Here is a [link](https://github.com/marekz/Web-Page-Status-Check), maybe help You.

Script simple check site code response. If status code is ok - 200 then do nothing. If status code is different than 200, send email notification to declared addresses in config.ini.

Finaly, in crontab I create a log file with site statuse.

```
1 * * * * /usr/bin/python3 /scripts/WebPageStatusCheck/main.py >> /scripts/WebPageStatusCheck/log/WebPageStatusCheck.log 2>&1
```

[Here](https://github.com/marekz/Web-Page-Status-Check/blob/main/CheckSiteStatus.py) check page status and return site status to main.py

```
import urllib.request


class CheckSiteStatus:
    def __init__(self):
        pass

    @staticmethod
    def check_site_url(url: str):
        url = 'http://' + url
        status = urllib.request.urlopen(url).getcode()
        return status
```

With best regards!

Answer (score 0):

You check it using

> 1:Ping your website
>
> 2:Go [here](https://www.site24x7.com/check-website-availability.html) and enter your website url to check availability

Make sure that your site is live on server.

Comment: I know if its online or not but the website does not detect if it's online or not and I was wondering if there was a way that automatically detected it and created a file on the server.

Answer (score 0):

Depends on the technology you are using for your website, you can program events when site goes up or down. Look at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4723610/919217) for example of shutdown event in ASP.NET.