# Is there a way to know that IIS wants to shut down my web app?

Tags: iis, asp.net-web-api

I am looking at using QueueBackgroundWorkItem for background work items in my ASP.NET Web-API2 REST server. This works perfectly for my use case in that all jobs being run get completed and written to a DB before the web app is shut down. And the replacement web app takes over and can return the completed jobs.

However, when I complete a job in the background thread, I don't want to start another if IIS wants to shut the app down. Is there a way to find out if IIS is waiting on tasks to complete and will then be shutting down?

Answer (score 0):

You could try to use configure in startup class. below is configure parameters:

IApplicationBuilder

IHostingEnvironment

ILoggerFactory

IApplicationLifetime

In the IApplicationLifetime interface you can register an event that is triggered when the application stops:

```
public class Startup
{
    public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IApplicationLifetime applicationLifetime)
    {
        applicationLifetime.ApplicationStopping.Register(OnShutdown);
    }

    private void OnShutdown()
    {
         //this code is called when the application stops
    }
}
```

you could refer this below links or more detail:

[How to listen to IIS shutdown event in ASP.NET](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4723573/how-to-listen-to-iis-shutdown-event-in-asp-net)

Comment: I tried this, this appears to be it is shutting down, not it wants to. I need it wants to.

Comment: @DavidThielen is this your answer https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4723573/how-to-listen-to-iis-shutdown-event-in-asp-net